# Perché, poiché, etc

Tags: word-choice, word-meaning, difference, english-comparison

Is there any significant difference between “perché” and “poiché”?  I’ve seen both used where “because” was the best English translation.

There were a couple of other words used the same way, but I can’t remember them now.

Comment: Very briefly, I have the impression that "poiché" is more similar to "since" in English

Comment: Let me add, partially beside the point, that *perché* also is the interrogative adverb corresponding to “why”, while *poiché* cannot be used so.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As you can read [here](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/poiche/), there is a subtle difference regarding the syntax:

> ["poiché" si adopera] per introdurre una prop. causale che precede la principale: *poiché la pensi così, lascio decidere a te* (quando invece la propr. causale segue la principale si preferisce «perché»: *lascio decidere a te perché so come la pensi*

I'll try to translate it:

> ["poiché" is used] to introduce a "because clause" before the main sentence: *poiché la pensi così, lascio decidere a te* (instead, if the main sentence comes first, "perché" is preferable: *lascio decidere a te perché so come la pensi*

Comment: Thanks.  I've checked Treccani before; didn't think of it this time.

Comment: It's not such a subtle difference, in the first case _perché_ is plain wrong. What is subtle is the difference between _poiché_ and _perché_ in the second case. Treccani only says that the latter is preferrable.

Answer (score 2):

As stated in the Treccani page linked above, "perché" can also be a synonym of "affinché", meaning "in order to". The syntax is similar to English:

"Perché tu possa finire il progetto, ti servirà almeno una settimana." means "In order to complete the project, you'll need at least a week".

The reversed form with the main sentence put first is also correct.

Comment: Please turn "finirà" into "finire"

Comment: Fixed “finire”.